# Is this variant of Subset Product NP-hard?

Tags: np-complete, decision-problem, subset-product

Given a set $Y$ with **whole number positive divisors** of $N$, is there a combination of divisors that have a product equal to $N$?

Does Subset Product remain NP-hard when **whole number divisors** are only allowed and there are no multiplicities in $Y$?

Comment: I generally exclude zero, if it's an issue.

Comment: @PålGD If you can reduce the Exact 3 Cover to my variant.

Comment: What are whole number positive divisors?

Comment: @xskxzr A positive number without fractions. A "whole" number. Not 3.15 or 3 12/25.